# Made a blog application in Mac terminal window. How do I see it in text editor?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, text-files, text-editor

This may seem like a dumb question.  I just started a Ruby on Rails class and my first assignment was to create a blog. I did that, but then the teacher tells everyone to look at the application in the text editor.  I am using Textwrangler for mac.  How do I see this application in text wrangler.  Do I open Textwrangler and just do a search for the name of my application called blog?

Comment: I would highly recommend textmate over Textwrangler. First navigate to the project directory and then use mate . to open the entire application.

Comment: probably easier to ask your classmate or teacher :D

Comment: Thanks deep.  I downloaded text wrangler and I was able to easily get to my application!  thanks! so much better